# Nginx fails to receive custom header when Redirected by Proxy server Node

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-location

I am running an NGINX server pointing to my proxy server which is running on Node. I am redirecting to `app/` from node using `express redirect`. I am also passing a custom header using `res.set("X-Custom-Header","XXX");` before the redirect. But the same header is not retrieved on `app/` route on NGINX. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You are setting a response header. This is not the same as the request headers that are received by `nginx` from the client.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve this in nginx route as I need to check few conditional statements based on the response header

Answer (score 1):

By default, nginx does not pass headers containing underscores.

Try:

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

See this [document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) for details.